# Heda - Affiliated Accounts

Tags: apex, trigger, managed-package

We installed the Heda in our org.

Every time we create a Program Enrollment - an affiliate account is related.

Since I don't have access to the managed trigger - If I want to change some fields inside the affiliation - before it created - Where should I do it?

I tried to do it via the HEDA Settings - But I don't sure it the right place.

Thanks!

Comment: BTW - the best support resource for the Higher Education Data Architecture package (HEDA) is the Salesforce Foundation's [Power of Us Hub](http://powerofus.force.com).   The Foundation maintains both HEDA and the Nonprofit Success Pack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all managed packages, even if you don't have access to the trigger, you can still write your own trigger for the specified object.

You can control "when" the record is updated by making sure to specify which trigger (before update, before insert, etc...). That being said, there's no way to control if your trigger is fired first of if their trigger is fired first so you will want to be conscious of this in the event that it doesn't work exactly as you envisioned it.

I would also advise familiarizing yourself with the [order of execution](https://sfdcpanther.wordpress.com/2017/10/11/triggers-and-order-of-execution-salesforce/) of triggers. You might be able to achieve your goal via a PB or Workflow which could also change the order in which the tasks execute (notice in the article how it mentions that updates via wf or PB fire the trigger a second time).

Comment: Thanks! I know I can create another trigger but It's not the best practice to do so, because I won't be able to control which trigger will run first.
But I did it with process builder that updating the record that created by Heda Trigger as you suggest. Thanks!